# Use user input to get mean (JAVA)

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to get user input, and use their input to calculate the mean. The problem I am having is that my code does not prompt the user for a integer to use to calculate the mean.

This is just a snippet of the code.

```
public static double[] getUserInput() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Double> inputList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    System.out.println("Please enter a number");


    System.out.println(inputList);
    double arr[] = new double[inputList.size()];
    System.out.println(inputList.size());
    return arr;
}

public static double arithmeticMean(double[] nums) {

    double mean = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    // gets the mean
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + nums[i];
        }
        mean = sum / nums.length;
    } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    return mean;
}
```

Comment: Only define the Scanner class not taking any number like `sc.nextDouble()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are never reading the input. The proper way to implement a scanner and read user input is as follows:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

double userInput = 0;

System.out.print("Please enter a number");

userInput = sc.nextDouble();    // This is what you are missing
```

So then you can either add the variable `userInput` into the ArrayList, or alternatively directly read into the ArrayList.

**Updated:**

This is the code you want. It will ask the user for the number of inputs, then it will add each input into the array.

```
public static double[] getUserInput() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Double> inputList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers you will be inputing");
    int numberOfInputs = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        double userInput = sc.nextDouble(); // Store user inputed double into temporary variable
        inputList.add(userInput); // Add temporary variable into ArrayList
    }
    sc.close();

    double[] arr = new double[inputList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = inputList.get(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Sorry I am not quite sure what you mean by adding userInput into the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're looking to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double[] arr = getUserInput();
    System.out.println("The Arithmetic Mean is " + arithmeticMean(arr));
}

public static Double[] getUserInput() {
    List<Double> inputList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please one number at a time, or [Enter] to end.");
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Next number: ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        if (input.equals(""))
            break;
        try {
            inputList.add(Double.parseDouble(input));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number, or [Enter] to end.");
        }
    }
    sc.close();

    Double[] arr = new Double[inputList.size()];
    arr = inputList.toArray(arr);
    return arr;
}

public static double arithmeticMean(Double[] nums) {
    double mean = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    // gets the mean
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + nums[i];
        }
        mean = sum / nums.length;
    } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return mean;
}
```