# (Java) Statistics program

Tags: java, statistics

I am trying to write a program that does the following.

1) Prompts user for a integer and stores it.
2) Uses the users input to calculate the 
***Arithmetic Mean
*Geometric Mean
*Min and Max** of the number that they just entered.

I've done most of it and from what I see, I asked the User for a input and stored it under the variable userInput in 
the first method.

I am not sure on how to use the userInput for Arithmetic Mean, Geometric Mean, and Min and Max.

```
public class SimpleStatistics {

    public static double[] getUserInput() {
        // Returns a string of doubles
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Create list
        List<Double> inputList = new ArrayList<Double>();

        // Getting input
        System.out.println("Please enter number");
        double userInput = sc.nextDouble();

        // See our new list
        System.out.println(inputList);
        double arr[] = new double[inputList.size()];
        System.out.println(inputList.size());
        return arr;
    }

    public static double arithmeticMean(double[] nums) {

        double mean = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + nums[i];
        }
        mean = sum / nums.length;

        return mean;
    }

    public static double geometricMean(double[] nums) {

        double gm = 1.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            gm *= nums[i];
        }
        gm = Math.pow(gm, 1.0 / (double) nums.length);
        return gm;
    }

    public static double[] minAndmax(double[] nums) {

        double min = nums[0];
        double max = nums[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] < min) {
                min = nums[i];
            } else if (nums[i] > max) {
                max = nums[i];
            } else {

            }
        }

        double[] minAndmax = { min, max };
        return minAndmax;
    }

    public static double[] scaleUp(double[] nums, int factor) {

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] *= factor;
        }
        return nums;
    }

    public static double[] scaleDown(double[] nums, int factor) {

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] /= factor;
        }
        return nums;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] input = { 1, 2.8, 5.3, 100, -5, -6.5 };

        System.out.println("Choose a option 1-6");

        boolean exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out
                    .println("1) Arithmetic mean, 2) Geometric mean, 3)  minAndmax, 4)  Scale Up, 5)  Scale Down, 6)  Quit");
            System.out.print("Input -> ");
            int choice = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

            switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                // Arithmetic mean
                System.out.println("Arithmetic mean");
                System.out.println(arithmeticMean(input));
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                // Geometric mean
                System.out.println("Geometric mean");
                System.out.println(arithmeticMean(input));
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                // Min and max
                System.out.println("Min and Max");
                for (double i : minAndmax(input)) {
                    System.out.print(i + ", ");
                }
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                // Scale Up
                System.out.println("Scale Up");
                System.out
                        .print("Please enter factor by which you want to scale -> ");
                int factor = sc.nextInt();
                for (double i : scaleUp(input, factor)) {
                    System.out.print(i + ", ");
                }
                break;
            }

            case 5: {
                // Scale Down
                System.out.println("Scale Down");
                System.out
                        .print("Please enter factor by which you want to scale -> ");
                int factor = sc.nextInt();
                for (double i : scaleDown(input, factor)) {
                    System.out.print(i + ", ");
                }
                break;
            }

            case 6: {
                exit = true;
                break;
            }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505820/use-user-input-to-get-mean-java If you still need help please ask.

Comment: Hi Bill thanks for your help, but I am still having trouble. I am pretty sure I am storing the userinput correctly, but I am not sure on how to use it for certain parts of the code.

Answer (score 2):

You are not actually adding your number to your double array. Change your getUserInput() function to the following:

```
public static double[] getUserInput() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many numbers are you entering?");
    double[] arr = new double[sc.nextInt()];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your number");
        arr[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    sc.close();

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `getUserInput` method to this:

```
public static double[] getUserInput() {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Double> inputList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    System.out.println("Please enter how many numbers you will be inputing");
    int numberOfInputs = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        double userInput = sc.nextDouble();
        inputList.add(userInput);
    }
    sc.close();

    double[] arr = new double[inputList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = inputList.get(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Then, in your main method, use the input by calling the method. E.g.

```
// Arithmetic mean
System.out.println("Arithmetic mean");
System.out.println(arithmeticMean(getUserInput()));
break;
```

I'm always happy to help, please ask if there is anything else.

Comment: It's unnecessary to create an array list for the getUserInput method. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The program works great! I understand a little more about calling methods. Quick question. When I run the program I get these errors after it finishes..

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)


 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)

 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)

 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)

 at simplestatistics.SimpleStatistics.main(SimpleStatistics.java:95)

Input -> Java Result: 1